# Unable to register brand new Yubico YubiKey 5C to account with MFA

Tags: multi-factor-authentication

My org is rolling out MFA ahead of the February 1, 2022 deadline. In fact, we've already rolled it out for our highest-privileged users, using both the Authenticator App. We received our YubiKey's Monday, and I eagerly registered my account with the key with no problem--it was amazing.

Today, when I tried to demo it to a subgroup of users, it failed. (I unregistered my key with the intent of re-registering it in the demo to show these users how simple it would be.) I was unable to register the same key and got this message:

> This site won't be able to use the U2F API after February 2022. If you
> own this site, you should change it to use the Web Authentication API.

I haven't seen this popout before. What does this mean? Is either U2F API or Web Authentication API something I can configure? What can I do to help my users register their security keys to meet the MFA requirement?

I should note that we chose to avoid the Authenticator App for our *general users*; we're sticking with exclusively using the security keys for our general users. When I tried re-registering my key, I logged out and tried registering it upon login, and from my user setup page both to no avail.

Comment: _I should note that we chose to avoid the Authenticator App for our general users; we're sticking with exclusively using the security keys for our general users_ - risky move because the error message you received has to do with Chrome [deprecating support](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/xHC3AtU_65A?pli=1) for U2F (aka FIDO v1) in lieu of a more modern WebAuthn (aka FIDO v2). Do your key and SF support WebAuthn? Perhaps. Is there an issue on SF side or with your key or the browser (WebAuthn is a JS API) ? You'll have to ping SF support and triage this....or avoid Chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a message from Chrome, indicating that it will be deprecating support for the current standard APIs that Salesforce is using to connect Security Keys. Salesforce will be updating their service to use WebAuthn, which is the standard they are moving towards. I was unable to skip the Chrome message and complete the process, and further unable to register my key in other browsers, including Firefox, Safari and MS Edge even though Edge supports security keys. It is possible that my company security settings are preventing me from completing this action.

Additionally, according to Salesforce, they are submitting an exception to Google to prevent this error message from showing up on salesforce.com and force.com domains but are not sure how long the turn around time from Google is.

I've gotten most of this information by communicating with Mat Hamlin at Salesforce via the trailhead website (the thread can be found [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000BuSpKSAV)).